# Parse Server: how to use the enviroment variables

Tags: parse-platform, docker-compose

I have installed the Parse Server inside a docker container and at the first glance it works. However there are a few enviroment variables (e.g. PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI) that need to be set. Some of their meanings are easy to guess. However, there are also environment variables, which I do not understand what they supposed to do.
Therefore I am curious, if there is a documentation of those environment variables.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full list of environment variables supported by the image can be found [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Options/Definitions.js).

You can also run `parse-server --help` for similar insights.

Usually, this kind of information can be found on the docker registry where the image is hosted or in the git repository.